# What do you call a convex polyhedron whose symmetry group is transitive on the facets?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, polyhedra, symmetry, polytopes

I'd like to know a name/source for the following concept:

Let $P$ be a convex polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Let $G$ be its symmetry group, and let $F$ be the collection of (top-dimensional) faces of $P$.  Note that $G$ acts on $F$.  Let's agree to call $P$ a *transitive* polyhedron if the action of $G$ on $F$ is transitive.

Have these been studied?  If so, what are they actually called?  What other nice properties do they enjoy?

Here are some examples of transitive polyhedra:

- the five platonic solids
- bipyramids (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipyramid) (Hence, there are infinitely many)
- trapezahedra (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezohedron) (e.g. the standard 10-sided die used in some role playing games)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned (and linked) [in the wikipedia page for Bipyramid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipyramid) and as mentioned in the properties box on t[he wikipedia for Trapezohedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezohedron), one term for the property is simply "face-transitive". When you [click the link on the page for the Bipyramid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face-transitive), you learn another term for the property: "isohedral", and a term for the polyhedra with this property: "isohedra".

There are a lot of things to say about isohedra, one of the more famous ones being to what extent they could be considered the "fair dice". (See, for example, [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46684/fair-but-irregular-polyhedral-dice).)

Comment: Thank you!  And you're right; I should have looked a bit more carefully.